# JSON Server returns empty response

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios, redux-form, json-server

So I have a `JSON` Server running

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "json-server -p 3004 -w db.json"
  },
```

and also created the `db.json` file for it :

```
{
    "streams": []
}
```

and I can see it running if I go to   `http://localhost:3004`

and then on the `React` side for action creator I have:

```
export const createStream = (formValues) => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    streams.post("/streams", formValues);
  };
};
```

where `streams` is the Axios wrapper like so:

```
import axios from "axios";

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost/3004",
});
```

and then I call it. I can see that even my form values are getting passed in as seen here:

[image]

but why is it failing eventually with a `NO_RESPONSE` error?

[image]

Comment: `/` is not the same as `:`. Use `http://localhost:3004` for the baseURL

Comment: OMG ! Thank you SO MUCH.  I had made that stupid typing error.  Yes it works now after fixing the URL format.

Answer (score 0):

try with the following (replace / with :  )

```
export default axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:3004",
});
```